# Microsoft Project - How to display week numbers in date boxes?

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2013

I would like to have week numbers displayed when I add a start and finish date for a task, in the Gantt Chart. I want the same type of convenience as in Outlook. Here is a screenshot of what this looks like in Outlook.

[image: office.microsoft.com]

This is [very easy](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-week-numbers-in-month-view-and-the-date-navigator-HA101993690.aspx) to set up in Outlook. I want exactly the same thing! Except in Project! Is this impossible in Project? Maybe I'm asking too much... I have searched for help online but the only thing I could find is [how to display options in the calendar view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/project-help/change-display-options-in-the-calendar-view-HA010148896.aspx) on Office support site. But it doesn't say what version of Project that applies to, and I can't see the options they describe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Week Number App for MS Project 2013

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/week-number-app-WA104367603.aspx?queryid=fd419919%2D7be8%2D4895%2Da0c6%2D7fbfd19af8ac&css=agito&CTT=1